# MvvmCross MvxFragment issue

Tags: android-fragments, mvvmcross

I cant find

> using MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.Fragging.Fragments;

for MvxFragment and when I use

> MvvmCross.Droid.FullFragging.Fragments;

or

> MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V4

I get this error

> IllegalArgumentException: already added:
>   Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat;

I have seen this post: 
[IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoIcsImpl;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030393/illegalargumentexception-already-added-landroid-support-v4-accessibilityservic][1])
but didn't helped me solve my issue.
Any suggestions?

Comment: As per the other SO QA you linked to, do you use other 3rd party NuGets or similar which may use some version of the Android Support packages? I haven't seen this anywhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V7.Fragging` and `MvvmCross.Droid.Support.V4` are deprecated. Use the new `MvvmCross.Droid.Support.Fragment`. Also see the upgrade documentation on this: https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/upgrading/upgrade-to-mvvmcross-50